# Understanding shared memory use for improvement in Numba

Tags: python, cuda, numba

I'm trying to learn more about the use of shared memory to improve performance in some cuda kernels in  `Numba`, for this I was looking at the [Matrix multiplication Example](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/cuda/examples.html) in the Numba documentation and tried to implement to see the gain.

This is my test implementation, I'm aware that the example in the documentation has some issues that I followed from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64197780/how-to-generalize-fast-matrix-multiplication-on-gpu-using-numba), so I copied the fixed example code.

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer
import numba
from numba import cuda, jit, int32, int64, float64, float32
import numpy as np
from numpy import *


@cuda.jit
def matmul(A, B, C):
    """Perform square matrix multiplication of C = A * B
    """
    i, j = cuda.grid(2)
    if i < C.shape[0] and j < C.shape[1]:
        tmp = 0.
        for k in range(A.shape[1]):
            tmp += A[i, k] * B[k, j]
        C[i, j] = tmp

# Controls threads per block and shared memory usage.
# The computation will be done on blocks of TPBxTPB elements.
TPB = 16

@cuda.jit
def fast_matmul(A, B, C):
    # Define an array in the shared memory
    # The size and type of the arrays must be known at compile time
    sA = cuda.shared.array(shape=(TPB, TPB), dtype=float32)
    sB = cuda.shared.array(shape=(TPB, TPB), dtype=float32)

    x, y = cuda.grid(2)

    tx = cuda.threadIdx.x
    ty = cuda.threadIdx.y
    bpg = cuda.gridDim.x    # blocks per grid

    # Each thread computes one element in the result matrix.
    # The dot product is chunked into dot products of TPB-long vectors.
    tmp = 0.
    for i in range(bpg):
        # Preload data into shared memory
        sA[ty, tx] = 0
        sB[ty, tx] = 0
        if y < A.shape[0] and (tx+i*TPB) < A.shape[1]:
            sA[ty, tx] = A[y, tx + i * TPB]
        if x < B.shape[1] and (ty+i*TPB) < B.shape[0]:
            sB[ty, tx] = B[ty + i * TPB, x]

        # Wait until all threads finish preloading
        cuda.syncthreads()

        # Computes partial product on the shared memory
        for j in range(TPB):
            tmp += sA[ty, j] * sB[j, tx]

        # Wait until all threads finish computing
        cuda.syncthreads()
    if y < C.shape[0] and x < C.shape[1]:
        C[y, x] = tmp

size = 1024*4
tpbx,tpby = 16, 16
tpb = (tpbx,tpby)
bpgx, bpgy = int(size/tpbx), int(size/tpby)
bpg = (bpgx, bpgy)
a_in = cuda.to_device(np.arange(size*size, dtype=np.float32).reshape((size, size)))
b_in = cuda.to_device(np.ones(size*size, dtype=np.float32).reshape((size, size)))
c_out1 = cuda.device_array_like(a_in)
c_out2 = cuda.device_array_like(a_in)

s = timer()
cuda.synchronize()
matmul[bpg,tpb](a_in, b_in, c_out1);
cuda.synchronize()
gpu_time = timer() - s

print(gpu_time)
c_host1 = c_out1.copy_to_host()
print(c_host1)

s = timer()
cuda.synchronize()
fast_matmul[bpg,tpb](a_in, b_in, c_out2);
cuda.synchronize()
gpu_time = timer() - s

print(gpu_time)
c_host2 = c_out2.copy_to_host()
print(c_host2)
```

The time of execution of the above kernels are essentially the same, actually the `matmul` was making faster for some larger input matrices. I would like to know what I'm missing in order to see the gain as the documentation suggests.

Thanks,
Bruno.

Answer (score 1):

I made a performance mistake in the code I put in [that other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64198479/1695960).  I've now fixed it.   In a nutshell this line:

```
    tmp = 0.
```

caused numba to create a 64-bit floating point variable `tmp`.  That triggered other arithmetic in the kernel to be promoted from 32-bit floating point to 64-bit floating point. That is inconsistent with the rest of the arithmetic and also inconsistent with the intent of the demonstration in the other answer.  This error affects both kernels.

When I change it in both kernels to

```
    tmp = float32(0.)
```

both kernels get noticeably faster, and on my GTX960 GPU, your test case shows that the shared code runs about 2x faster than the non-shared code (but see below).

The non-shared kernel also has a performance issue related to memory access patterns.  Similar to the indices swap in [that other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64198479/1695960), *for this particular scenario only*, we can rectify this problem simply by reversing the assigned indices:

```
j, i = cuda.grid(2)
```

in the non-shared kernel.  This allows that kernel to perform approximately as well as it can, and with that change the shared kernel runs about 2x faster than the non-shared kernel.  Without that additional change to the non-shared kernel, the performance of the non-shared kernel is much worse.

Comment: Okay, this is definitely something I would never have realized, thank you :)

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more about why the order of the indexes in the non shared kernel may have a performance issue ?  Because this isn't quite clear to me

Comment: You might wish to take advantage of resources such as [this](https://www.olcf.ornl.gov/cuda-training-series/) to get an orderly introduction to CUDA (or read [the programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html)).  The index order creates one case where **coalescing** of global loads occurs, and the other case not. This is covered extensively here on the `cuda` tag.  The uncoalesced case is worse for performance. Same observation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68188791). I was going to try to help you there, but you posted code that will not run.

Comment: Okay @Robert, thanks very much for the explanation and link on the training series, I will definitively take a look. I just posted there the attempt to run the code in multiple streams, as I thought that would improve performance, but now I get that it is better to do with just one kernel launch. I work with LBM and I'm trying to speed up some simulations, I already gained about 45x speed that the regular python code, but I'm looking where else I can improve performance. Thanks for all the help.